Mean Curvature of Graphs over Hypersurfaces
Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^{n}$ be an open and $f : U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a smooth map. Then the mean curvature of the graph is given by $$\mathrm{div}\left(\frac{\mathrm{grad}\,f}{\sqrt{1 + |\mathrm{grad}\,f|^2}}\right)$$
Consider a more general case where $S \subseteq\mathbb R^{n+1}$ is an embedded hypersurface with a smooth $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Let $\nu : S \rightarrow \mathbb S^{n}$ be the Gauss map of $S$. Then the graph of $f$ is given by $\{ x + f(x) \nu(x) : x \in S\}$. Suppose this graph is an embedded hypersurface. Is it true that the mean curvature is given by the same formula as above?
I considered this question with $S = \mathbb S^2$, but, even in this case, the computation seems to get messy. I would appreciate it if anyone could confirm whether the above formula continues to hold and provide some references that offer a proof. If not, I would like to know some formulas for specific $S$. In particular, I am interested in the case when $S$ is a cone.

The above formula will NOT hold in general for a simple reason. If one sets $f$ to be identically zero, then the graph is just $S$. The above formula then says that $S$ has mean curvature equal to zero everywhere, which may not be the case.

But, if I add the mean curvature of $S$ to the above formula, then that might work?
